# Hex byte values to DWORD (ascii) format

Tags: c++, byte, ascii, dword

Need a conversion from byte values to DWORD (ascii based)!

**Example:**

INPUT: `1F 12 BA 43` (saved in `std::vector<BYTE>`)

OUTPUT: `31 46 31 32 42 41 34 33` (ascii values of input) -> also stored in a `std::vector<BYTE>`

Easiest method to do this conversion?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef std::vector<BYTE> Vector;

Vector hex2ascii(Vector const &src) {
  Vector result;
  for ( Vector::const_iterator iter = src.begin(); iter!=src.end(); iter++ ) {
    BYTE item = *iter;
    unsigned bits=8;
    do {
      bits -= 4;
      result.push_back("0123456789ABCDEF"[(item>>bits)&15u]);
    } while(bits);
  }
  return result;
}
```